# Page loading with CSS Transitions

Tags: jquery, css

I was looking at one of my favorite sites and I've been trying to find out how their pages work: http://hellomonday.com/ What I'm pertaining to are the animations that happen when you click on a new page. Is this through ajax? I'm really clueless and I don't know where to start.

Thanks

Comment: have you try looking at the source?

Comment: I did and it's really obfuscated. You should know that I wouldn't resort to asking if I found the answer in the source.

Comment: you do know google chrome un-obfuscate the code ;)

Comment: I meant obfuscated in the sense that I can't understand it

Comment: sorry dude i cant see what you mean, all is there ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**

They are done using ajax and the reason why you see the URL is changing without complete reload is HTML5's PUSH and POP STATE

PUSH and POP STATE allow you to change the URL of the page without reload, like we use to do using hash

REF - http://html5doctor.com/history-api/